# Logical flaw in CS50 Problem Set 4 - Filter (Edges)?

Tags: c, debugging, cs50

I am having some issues fulfilling the requirements for the edges filter in Problem Set 4 of CS50. A description of the problem can be found here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/more/. My code makes sense to me, so hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me, as I have been staring at my code for days on end now ): To be clear, my code does compile, so I do not think there are any bugs per se, but probably a logical flaw in my thinking.

My code is as follows:

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE tempimage[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tempimage[i][j] = image[i][j];
            int sGxRed = 0;
            int sGxGreen = 0;
            int sGxBlue = 0;
            int sGyRed = 0;
            int sGyGreen = 0;
            int sGyBlue = 0;
            if (j + 1 < width)
            {
                sGxRed += 2 * image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                sGxGreen += 2 * image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGxBlue += 2 * image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            if (j > 0)
            {
                sGxRed += -2 * image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                sGxGreen += -2 * image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGxBlue += -2 * image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            if (i + 1 < height)
            {
                sGyRed += 2 * image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                sGyGreen += 2 * image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                sGyBlue += 2 * image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
            }
            if (i > 0)
            {
                sGyRed += -2 * image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                sGyGreen += -2 * image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                sGyBlue += -2 * image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
            }
            if (i + 1 < height && j + 1 < width)
            {
                sGxRed += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                sGxGreen += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGxBlue += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                sGyRed += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                sGyGreen += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGyBlue += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            if (i > 0 && j + 1 < width)
            {
                sGxRed += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                sGxGreen += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGxBlue += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                sGyRed += -1 * image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                sGyGreen += -1 * image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGyBlue += -1 * image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            if (i > 0 && j > 0)
            {
                sGxRed += -1 * image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                sGxGreen += -1 * image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGxBlue += -1 * image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                sGyRed += -1 * image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                sGyGreen += -1 * image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGyBlue += -1 * image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            if (i + 1 < height && j > 0)
            {
                sGxRed += -1 * image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                sGxGreen += -1 * image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGxBlue += -1 * image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                sGyRed += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                sGyGreen += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                sGyBlue += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            }
            int sRed = 0;
            int sGreen = 0;
            int sBlue = 0;
            sRed = round((float)(sqrt(sGxRed^2 + sGyRed^2)));
            if (sRed > 255)
            {
                sRed = 255;
            }
            sGreen = round((float)(sqrt(sGxGreen^2 + sGyGreen^2)));
            if (sGreen > 255)
            {
                sGreen = 255;
            }
            sBlue = round((float)(sqrt(sGxBlue^2 + sGyBlue^2)));
            if (sBlue > 255)
            {
                sBlue = 255;
            }
            tempimage[i][j].rgbtRed = sRed;
            tempimage[i][j].rgbtGreen = sGreen;
            tempimage[i][j].rgbtBlue = sBlue;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = tempimage[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = tempimage[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = tempimage[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I am very new to coding. Prior to taking this course, I have only tried my hand at a little VBA. This is my first time coding in C and the learning curve for CS50 is steep, so pardon me if my question is trivial!

Thank you all in advance! :)

P.S Apart from my actual question, please feel free to comment on how my code can be more efficient/shortened as well. I am always open to different points of view!

Comment: Do not describe a problem as “does not work at all”. Provide a [mre], including providing a complete program that another person can copy, compile, and execute without change, exact input that demonstrates the problem, exact output that is observed, and output that is expected instead. If they are not obvious, state what differences there are between the observed output and the expected output.

Comment: @Eric hello! Thank you for your advice. Allow me to first apologise if my post did not adhere to the site’s requirements. As mentioned in the post, I am quite new here. In response to your comment, I did show my complete code for the given function, though, so I assume that anyone who wants to try it out for himself/herself could simply copy that?

Comment: If you take the working code and include a main() with an example of how you call the function, you can submit the whole thing to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, if you want a general code review and suggestions of what to improve. Keep in mind that the Code Review site requires complete and working code though, a literal copy/paste of the working program.

Comment: @Lundin I see! Thank you for that as well! I will certainly keep that in mind :)

Comment: There are multiple reasons the code for one function alone is insufficient to diagnose a problem, including (0) we do not have sample input for it, nor observed results nor expected results, and we might not be able to easily construct a case for which it fails nor understand why you think it fails, (1) the function has prerequisites not shown in the code, such as a definition for `RGBTRIPLE`, which can affect how the function behaves, (2) the cause of errors may be something in your program besides the function source code, such as `#define` statements that break the function in subtle ways,…

Comment: … and (3) the function may actually be behaving correctly but your interpretation of it is incorrect. This is not an all-inclusive list of possibilities. Ideally, a question presents a [mre] in which there is **one very specific situation** — one set of complete source code that can be executed with **no question** about what the complete source code is, compiled with a specific compiler version and specific switches, linked in a specific way, executed on a specific system, with specific input, specific observed output, and specified desired output. This reduces the problem to…

Comment: … an unambiguous easily reproduced test case with the simple question about why it produces X instead of Y. It removes guesswork about what is missing, what the circumstances are, and so on. Furthermore, when somebody prepares an [mre], the processes of slicing away unnecessary parts to make it minimal often reveals useful information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see! Okay I will definitely take that into account when writing my next question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common misunderstanding: `^` does not mean power-of, it means bit-wise XOR, which is not what you want here. Replace it with `pow()` from math.h.

Or in case of power of 2 specifically, simply do `variable * variable`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is literally the only thing that was wrong! Allow me to say how happy I am to know that there was no logical flaw in my code :) It really is a wonderful feeling to know your code functions properly, more so when you have done it all by yourself (well mostly, because if not for your help I would still be banging my head against the wall. No way I could ever have figured that out on my own!). Thank you again!